# Datagridview event for enter key

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a bound datagridview.when i select a cell in datagridview and press enter, i want a event to be raised which passes the selected cell's row's first column value to another form. how to do it?

Comment: what did you try? is this winforms? how do you bind the data? can you show some code?

Comment: You can subscribe to the key events for the cell and then act when you find the Enter key.

Answer (score 3):

I solved this problem by using `_EditingControlShowing` Event to the datagridview and using PreviewKeyDown to the cell here the code:

```
DataGridView1.EditingControlShowing += new DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventHandler (DataGridView1_EditingControlShowing);

private void dbg_EditingControlShowing (object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e) {
        TextBox txb = e.Control as TextBox;
        txb.PreviewKeyDown += (S, E) => {
            if (E.KeyCode == Keys.Enter) {
                DataGridView1.CurrentCell = dbg.CurrentRow.Cells["Column_name"];
                //Or any code you ...
            }
        };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
void TextBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{ 
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter) 
    { 
        e.Handled = true; 
    } 
}

void TextBox1_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, PreviewKeyDownEventArgs e) 
{ 
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Return)
    {
        /* Your code here! */ 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is for Winforms, you can subscribe to one of the Key events and use that event.

For example, here is using the `KeyUp` event.

```
 private void myDataGridView_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
 {
      // nothing is selected
      if (myDataGridView.SelectedRows.Count == 0)
          return;

      if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
      {
           string firstColumnValue = myDataGridView.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString();

           // passes the value through the constructor to the 
           //   second form.
           MySecondForm f2 = new MySecondForm(firstColumnValue);
           f2.Show();
      }
 }
```

Comment: it is giving error- System.NullReferenceException was unhandled
  Message="Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Answer (score 0):

Form 1 Code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("ID");
        dt.Columns.Add("Name");
        dt.Rows.Add();
        dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1][0] = "1";
        dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1][1] = "Stackoverflow";
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
    }
    string ID = string.Empty;
    private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        ID = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells["ID"].Value.ToString();
    }
       private void dataGridView1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            Form2 frmTwo = new Form2(ID);
            frmTwo.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

Form 2 Code:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public string Id = string.Empty;
    public Form2(string FormOneID)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Id = FormOneID;
    }

    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("FormOne ID" + Environment.NewLine + Id + Environment.NewLine + "Displaying on FormTwo");
    }
}
```